# Turn off FPS monitor in chrome while DEV TOOLS is open

Tags: google-chrome

It's crazy I have to post about this to get an answer but there is no way of googling this

I somehow made the FPS box show whenever I'm in developer tools, and I cannot find out how to hide it again.

if I google, they give me this link:
chrome://flags/#show-fps-counter
This option shows the option with dev-tools closed, but not with dev-tools open.
Please don't tell me to go to that link, yes I tried it and rebooted chrome.

I need to do UX/UI but the fact that the top right corner is obfuscated is making it very frustrating, especially because i cannot right click to close it, or view/window -> show/hide fps, or any simple answer.

Why is it so hard and hidden to do this? Even searching in the "help" for fps gives no results

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#counter-display - This says its for dev area

Comment: Yeah I actually saw this too before posting, but go try it, he doesn't specify what "settings menu" to use, and I've tried all of them, even went to chrome://settings/ and did a search for "fps" and nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a "Show FPS meter" checkbox buried in the Rendering subtab of the Elements tab:

[image]

+1 for how obscure and hard to find this was.

Comment: Finally the real answer! 20 internets for you my friend.

Comment: If you don't see that checkbox option, then go to chrome://flags/#show-fps-counter and click disable.

Evidently it's possible to permanently turn on said feature via chrome://flags, which then removes its corresponding toggle checkbox in the devtools plugin.

I just went through this for another feature.  chrome://flags/#composited-layer-borders   No idea how I managed to permanently turn it on.  But took me a while to figure out how to turn it off again.

Answer (score 1):

Got it

Open Developer Tools

Click the gear in top right of developer tools

Scroll to bottom "Restore Defaults and reload"

Still isn't a "Real Answer" but it did what I wanted

Stupid how that restore defaults is different from the Chrome > preferences > restore defaults

Answer (score 0):

Just restored chrome to default settings because no one could answer

Edit: Don't do this if you are trying to solve this problem, as it will not change dev-tools settings